# How to make my custom report template appear?

Tags: extension, custom-reports

This is CiviCRM 4.6.22 / Drupal 7 where I used civix to copy one of the give contact reports:

> civix --copy=CRM_Report_Form_Contact_Summary generate:report MCat null

It also appears registered in the Report manager. However I cannot find and therefore not use it when I look in Reports > Contact Reports

I tried reinstalling the module, looked for clues in the log file. Any helpful advice is appreciated!

Comment: Is it there if you click New Contact Report?

Comment: Good question! Yes, it is? I get it now. At Reports > Contact Reports the templates are not listed but the actual reports, when a template was used. 

Thank you! If you can formulate it as an answer, it will bring you the appropriate credit for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Expanding comment as an answer...)

Reports > Contact Reports shows the Reports that have been created from Report Templates.  Your extension adds a Report Template, so from Report > Contact Reports, click 'New Contact Report' to see the templates. Select your template, configure and save as a new Report.